# Doctrine executeUpdate array parameter

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

How can I do update in doctrine, with array, so I don't do for loop for each time (I just want to do 1 call to database)

```
$myarray = [1, 2, 3];
$sql = "UPDATE `mytable` SET is_processing = :is_processing, end_time=NOW() WHERE id = :id";

$result = $this->connection->executeUpdate(
    $sql,
    array(
        'is_processing' => false,
        'id' => $myarray // This is unknown number amount of array
    )
);
```

What I'm trying to achieve is: 
it should update the table with field is_processing = false, endTime become current time, where id = whatever the array point to

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `IN` clause in your query.

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET is_processing = :is_processing, end_time=NOW() WHERE id IN(:ids)
```

then

```
$result = $this->connection->executeUpdate(
    $sql,
    array(
        'is_processing' => false,
        'ids' => [3, 25]
    ),
    array(
        'ids' => \Doctrine\DBAL\Connection::PARAM_INT_ARRAY
    )
);
```

Comment: I meant, the id is an array, for unknown number of array

Comment: I'm not sure. I think so

Comment: when I ran your code, nothing really happen. no row got changed. there is notice "Notice: Array to string conversion in /Users/project/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOStatement.php on line 67"

Comment: cool it worked.. so, any idea why we need to add the 3rd paramenters, param int array?

Comment: The 3rd argument are the parameter types.  you can see them [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion)

Comment: @Federkun parameter types (correct link): https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/current/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#list-of-parameters-conversion